# How to lead with safe area in Objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller, safearealayoutguide, safeareaview

Sorry if this question already exists, but i don't know how exactly to ask. I have a project in Objective-C, in appDelegate there's a view controller being instantiate on window root, but when I run in new iphones i have the following problem with safe area and layout guide:

[image: My view controller from root]

It's not filling all the screen, i tried to set UIScreen bounds but doesn't worked.

Comment: There is no problem with app delegate or screen bounds. Check your view controller.

Comment: set up a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` for your project, instead of the launch images.

Comment: Thanks @holex, there's something not set when i start the project with Objective-C, i recreate the launchScreen in swift and it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout constraints from storyboard do as follows:

1. Select the view, image, whatever... that you want to constraint to the margins of the screen
2. Add to it new constraints as usual, by clicking in the right down buttons of the storyboard
3. Uncheck the option "Constraint to margins", as shown in image
4. Select your view, not **the safe area**, by clicking in the dropdown menu. As shown in the image
5. Then write 0 value for the constraint.
6. Click on Add constraints and voila!

[image]